# Compare two folders, return full path of different file

Tags: python, comparison, list-comprehension

I have a script which should compare files in folders and subfolders. The new files should be copied later. This is the function I use to create the lists.

```
def fullNames(source):
    matches = []

    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
                matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return matches
```

This function returns lists like this:

```
list1 =  ['C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-18\\file1.xlsx',
          'C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-18\\file2.xlsx',
          'C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-18\\file3.xlsx',
          'C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-18\\file4.xlsx',
          'C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-18\\file5.xlsx']

list2 =  ['C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-17\\file1.xlsx',
          'C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-17\\file2.xlsx',
          'C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-17\\file3.xlsx',
          'C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-17\\file4.xlsx']
```

To compare the files, I have to compare the basenames of each file.

```
list1_short = [os.path.basename(file) for file in list1]
list2_short = [os.path.basename(file) for file in list2]

result = [item for item in list1_short if item not in list2_short]
result

Out[134]: ['file5.xlsx']
```

This works, but I need to return the full path of that file, not the basename. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

This would be the desired result:

```
['C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-18\\file5.xlsx']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just get rid of `list2_short` actually:

```
list1 =  ['C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-18/file1.xlsx',
          'C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-18/file2.xlsx',
          'C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-18/file3.xlsx',
          'C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-18/file4.xlsx',
          'C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-18/file5.xlsx']

list2 =  ['C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-17/file1.xlsx',
          'C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-17/file2.xlsx',
          'C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-17/file3.xlsx',
          'C:/Users/langma/Desktop/EDI/Downloadfolder/EDI_2020-05-17/file4.xlsx']


existing_names = [os.path.basename(item) for item in list2]
missing_files = [item for item in list1 if os.path.basename(item) not in existing_names]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by changing the way you are getting result,

`result = [list1[i] for i in range(len(list1_short)) if list1_short[i] not in list2_short]`

Comment: You may be interested in learning about the `zip()` and `enumerate()` functions...

Answer (score 0):

```
list1_short = [os.path.basename(file) for file in list1]
list2_short = [os.path.basename(file) for file in list2]
missing_files=[]
for i,item in enumerate(list1_short):
    if item not in list2_short:
        missing_files.append(list1[i])
```